# Assistance with DB2 query

Tags: db2

I have a query that produced nearly 2 million rows. The issue is, they now want me to dedup it but keep only the most current timestamp for each account per template id (there are 4 templates). My brain is just not getting what needs to be done. I know I'm fairly close, like getting the max(ts) for each account and grouping those by the account, max(ts), and template, but can't figure out how to put it together. Currently, it's just a simple select statement, but when they got the results, they realized there were too many duplicates and only want distinct accounts for each template. Thanks in advance.

```
select a.account, a.template, a.tracking_no, a.ts from table1 A,
(select distinct(account, template, max(ts)) from table1 where template in (<TEMPLATE LIST>) group by account, template, ts) b
where a.account = b.account and a.template = b.template and
      a.ts = b.ts with ur;
```

I know I'm close, but my brain is refusing to connect the dots. I edited this with something else I came up with. Don't know if this will do it, but while I'm waiting for a response, I can try it.

Comment: Please, edit your question with some sample data and the results desired.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the rows you need. Then, filtering is trivial.

For example:

```
select *
from (
  select
    t.*,
    row_number() over(partition by account, template order by ts desc) as rn
  from table1 t
  where template in (<TEMPLATE LIST>) 
) x
where rn = 1
```

For good performance I would consider an index on: `(template, account, ts)`.

Comment: This works for db2?

Comment: I don't know about z/OS or iSeries, but it surely works in DB2 LUW. See [running example](https://dbfiddle.uk/LIUgISub).